# How to display pages from a nested folder in asp.net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-3.1

I get the below exception when I try to run the application , I know the reason is it couldn't find the file. But any alternative to serve this file?

Folder structure :
[image]

I Tried using "UseContentRoot" but couldn't fix the issue

```
   CreateHostBuilder(args).UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\PersonalTab").Build().Run();
```

Exception : 
InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml

When I try the views from outside of "PersonalTab" folder it works fine, but for my requirement it needs to be inside "PersonalTab" folder?

Note : Am using asp.net core 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure RazorViewEngineOptions to also look under PersonalTab folder. I tried to recreate a project and added this to Startup class ConfigureServices method and it worked for me:

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o =>
        {
            o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/PersonalTab/Views/{1}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
            o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/PersonalTab/Views/Shared/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
        });
```

Ref: [Change Default Location of Views and Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/c50d3f14-7048-4b4f-84f4-1b28cb0f9d96.aspx)